# Three js lookAt function failing

Tags: javascript, math, 3d, three.js

I have the following scene visable here: http://gravient.thomashoek.com/drag_example/

In the initial mode the text looks at the mouse. but when you make sertain mouse movements the text seems to flip the direct of looking at the mouse. As far as i figured out this happens when the mouse crosses the middle of the canvas.

A quick in depth explanation of the problem: So when the mouse is at the top of the screen the mesh looks at the bottom of the screen. And this is the same for all directions.

But when you move the mouse again in a certain undefined manner the problem fixes it self.

So my question is: How can i prevent this from happening?

My code to do the lookAt is as following:

```js
var data = {
 text : ["THE NEXT","POINT","OF VIEW"],
 size : 5,
 height : 2,
 curveSegments : 12,
 line_height : 1.7
};

function generateTextGeometry(mesh) {

 var y_start =  (0 - data.text.length * data.size / 2 - data.size / 2 - (data.text.length - 1) * data.line_height)/2;
 var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();

 loader.load( '../data/suisse_2.json', function ( font ) {

  for (var i = data.text.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   var geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( data.text[i], {
    font: font,
    size: data.size,
    height: data.height,
    curveSegments: data.curveSegments
   });
   geometry.center();
   mesh.children[i].geometry = geometry;
   mesh.children[i].position.y = y_start;

   if (i < data.text.length) {
    y_start += (data.size + data.line_height);
   }else{
    y_start += data.size;
   }
  }
 });
}



//global vars for al the desired options all are false because we dont know if it will work. 
var current_interaction_mode = null;
var webcam = false;
var gyroscope = false;
var followMouse = false;
var dragMouse = true;
var rotation_vals = {
 x: -0.51,
 y: 0.51,
 range: 0.2
}

check_user_hardware();

//check if all the wanted options are available
function check_user_hardware(){
 window.addEventListener("devicemotion", function(event){
  if(event.rotationRate.alpha || event.rotationRate.beta || event.rotationRate.gamma){
   if (!gyroscope) {
    gyroscope = true;
    current_interaction_mode = 'gyroscope_option';
    set_user_ui_elements();
   }
  }else{
   followMouse = true;
   current_interaction_mode = 'followMouse_option';
   set_user_ui_elements();
   window.addEventListener('mousemove', get_user_mouse_pos);
  }
  calculate_rotation_mesh_pos(event.rotationRate.beta, event.rotationRate.gamma);
 });
}

function get_user_mouse_pos(event){
 rotation_vals.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
 rotation_vals.y =  - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
}

function calculate_rotation_mesh_pos(x_angle, y_angle){
 // rotation_vals.x = some calculation that needs to be done here
 // rotation_vals.y = some calculation that needs to be done here
}


function set_user_ui_elements(){

 if (followMouse) {
  $('#followMouse_option').show();
 }
 if (gyroscope) {
  $('#gyroscope_option').show();
 }
 if (dragMouse) {
  $('#dragMouse_option').show();
 }
 if (current_interaction_mode == 'followMouse_option') $('#followMouse_option').css('color', '#ff0000');
 if (current_interaction_mode == 'gyroscope_option') $('#gyroscope_option').css('color', '#ff0000');

}




var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( window.innerWidth / - 40, window.innerWidth / 40, window.innerHeight / 40, window.innerHeight / - 40, 0, 2000 );
camera.position.z = 1000;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 1 );
document.getElementById('interactive_container').appendChild( renderer.domElement );


//set up interaction parameters
var fakeMouseLoc = new THREE.Vector3();
var orbit = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
orbit.enableZoom = false;
orbit.enableKeys = false;
orbit.enablePan = false;
orbit.enabled = false;

//generate the text mesh
var mesh = new THREE.Object3D();
for (var i = data.text.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
 mesh.add( new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.Geometry(),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
   color: 0xFFFFFF
  })
 ));
}

var options =  generateTextGeometry(mesh);
scene.add( mesh );


var render = function(){

 if (current_interaction_mode == 'followMouse_option' || current_interaction_mode == 'gyroscope_option') {
  fakeMouseLoc.set(rotation_vals.x, rotation_vals.y, rotation_vals.range);
  mesh.lookAt(fakeMouseLoc); 
 }

 renderer.render( scene, camera );
 requestAnimationFrame( render );
}; 

render();




window.addEventListener( 'resize', function () {
 camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
 renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}, false );

function add_geometry_to_container(container){
 container.add( new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.Geometry(),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
   color: 0xFFFFFF
  })
 ));
}

function clear_geometry_of_container(container, empty){
 if (!empty) {
  container.children[0].geometry.dispose();
  container.children[0].material.dispose();
  container.remove(container.children[0]);
 }else{
  for (var i = container.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   container.children[i].geometry.dispose();
   container.children[i].material.dispose();
   container.remove(container.children[i]);
  }
 }
}

function invert_color(state){
 if(state){
  console.log("switch to white bg");
  renderer.setClearColor( 0xFFFFFF, 1 );
  for (var i = data.text.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   mesh.children[i].material.color.setHex( 0x000000, 1 );
  }
 }else{
  console.log("switch to black bg");
  renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 1 );
  for (var i = data.text.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   mesh.children[i].material.color.setHex( 0xFFFFFF, 1 );
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="../supporting_files/general/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../supporting_files/3d_interactive/three.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../supporting_files/3d_interactive/OrbitControls.js"></script>
 <script src='../supporting_files/3d_interactive/geometry.js'></script>
 <script src="../supporting_files/general/check_features.js"></script>
 <script src="../supporting_files/main_page_js/desktop_main.js"></script>
<script src="../supporting_files/3d_interactive/main_3d_scene.js"></script>
```

If you need more info, context or something is unclear pls let me know so i can clarify :)

Comment: You probably need to post more code. I suspect the the lookAt function only works for objects in the root of the scene.

Comment: sure i will add all the code but be warned it is a lot

Comment: so i added about all the javascript, hope this gives some more insight. I did it in a snippet for convenience, but it wont run :$

Comment: the html is to show the order of js files being loaded/ used

Comment: Try pushing your `mesh` back a little (`mesh.position.z = -1`). The depth between where `mesh` is positioned vs. the mouse position vector you're giving `lookAt` is very shallow, which may cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion i will try this :)

Comment: I tried your suggestion with multiple values for the z-pos and i changed the mapping for the mouse to give more room to move. But the probleem seemed to keep occurring. Could this be a bug?

Comment: maybe i found an other parameter that could influence this behavior. On page load i set some fake mouse coordinates to create some initial rotation on the mesh. Could this mess with the behavior of the lookat function? When the user moves his mouse these coordinates get replaced by the real ones.